# Scoring for survey questionnaire python tkinter, assigning importance to questions

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hi I am a beginner with python tkinter and am working on a capstone project to develop a readiness assessment tool. I have written code for some extent. I have questions that have priority. 
Following are example questions:
•   20% Has your organization completed a strategic planning process in the last year? (Yes (5), No (0), Maybe (1))
•   10% Do you have an Internal/Physician/Administrator/Clinical champion to promote change? (Yes (5), No (0), Maybe (2.5))

Now for example if user selects Yes(5) should be multiplied with 20% to get actual score and then all the scores should be added to get a score out of 100.

I am struck at how to get the results using result button.
Following is part of my code:

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


    label = tk.Label(self, text="ORGANIZATIONAL READINESS", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=1)


    label1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Has your organization completed a strategic planning process in the last year?")
    label1.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    var = tk.StringVar()

    R1 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text = "Yes", variable = var, value = "Yes")
    R2 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text = "No", variable = var, value = "No")
    R3 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text = "May be", variable = var, value = "Maybe")
    label1.pack(anchor='w')
    R1.pack(anchor='w')
    R2.pack(anchor='w')
    R3.pack(anchor='w')


    ResultsButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Results")
    ResultsButton.pack(padx=30,pady=10)

    button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                    command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button1.pack()

    progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient= HORIZONTAL, length= 200)
    progressbar.pack()
    progressbar.config(mode = 'determinate', maximum = 15.0, value = 4.0 )
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: in `Button` use `command=` to assign function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use command=SOMEFUNCTIONHERE in your ResultsButton. For example:

```
ResultsButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Results", command = self.getResults)
ResultsButton.pack(padx=30,pady=10)
```

now you need to define the function self.getResults (notice no parenthesis in the tk.Button line)

```
def getResults(self): # This is a function inside your PageOne class
    user_answer = var.get() # Gets the value of var based on which radio button was selected
    if user_answer == "Yes":
        # Give them 5 * 0.2 points
    if user_answer == "No":
        # Give them 0 * 0.2 points
```